# scan all catalog and filtering files using globe

Tags: python, python-3.x

there is a function that searches for all files in the directory, how do I apply it to it so that it returns only the files I need?

```
def scan_recursive(path):
    with os.scandir(path) as it:
        for entry in it:
            if entry.is_file():
                yield path + "/" + entry.name
            else:
                yield from scan_recursive(entry.path)

for file_path in scan_recursive('C:/test/1'):
    x.append(file_path)
```

for example, only files with the approximate name "2018-*-photo.jpg "

I read about the possibilities of "globe.globe" but could not apply them correctly

I did so, but I don't understand how I can write the results to the append list does not help

```
def scan_recursive(directory, path):
    # x = []
    for pathes in path:
        files = Path(directory).glob(f'**/{pathes}')
        for file in files:
            if file.is_file():
                print(file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the pathlib library:

```
pathlib.Path("your_path").glob("2018-*-photo.jpg")
```

or if you want files in subdirectories too:

```
pathlib.Path("your_path").glob("**/2018-*-photo.jpg")
```